# Usar condição no Javascript para operações matemáticas

Tags: javascript, html

Olá! Estou tentando efetuar um cálculo diferente em JS para que de acordo com o número de funcionários, o valor total seja alterado.

A condição seria a seguinte:
Inserindo um valor de 1 a 5 no input, este valor é multiplicado por 50 e apresentado no span em valor monetário;
Inserindo um valor de 6 a 10, o valor é multiplicado por 45 e o resultado é apresentado no span em valor monetário;

E por aí vai. A pessoa precisa inserir o valor no campo para que apareça no span o resultado mas é preciso seguir as condições.

Tentei com if, else if porém não obtive sucesso, sei que é algo bem simples então peço ajuda dos universitários.

Há também a possibilidade do resultado aparecer na hora sem pressionar botão ou a tecla TAB?

O meu código está assim:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  Número de Funcionários: <input type="number" id="num1" onblur="calcular();" />
  <span id="resultado"></span>

  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (num1 < 5) {

function calcular() {
var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
var func1 = 50;
var elemResult = document.getElementById("resultado");
elemResult.textContent = "O resultado é " + String(num1 * func1) + ".";
}

}

else if (condição ??) {

function calcular() {
var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
var func1 = 10;
var elemResult = document.getElementById("resultado");
elemResult.textContent = "O resultado é " + String(num1 * func1) + ".";
}

}

</script>
```

Comment: Arthur, formate melhor o código amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o If dentro da function, e não o IF para condicionar qual function será.

```
function calcular() {
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var elemResult = document.getElementById("resultado");
    var func1 = 0;


    if (num1 < 5) {
        func1 = 50
    } else if (num < 10) {
        func1 = 45
    }

    elemResult.textContent = "O resultado é " + String(num1 * func1) + "."
};
```

para utilizar sem precisar pressionar, apenas quando digitar, utileza o [onKeyPress](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp), onKeyDown

Comment: Perfeito, alterei algumas condições do código e funcionou corretamente.
Muito Obrigado!